# Drupal HOOK_views_pre_render not working for simple change of $views->result

Tags: drupal, module, view

well I haven't been able to find the problem with my little custom module for a couple of days, I'm hoping some clever and kind person might spot my issue ;)

So I am creating a simple module that runs on a certain view type, this view contains images, the images have alt tags, I want to amend these alt tags by using the url alias and sticking this on the end of the alt tag..

I have successfully found the data in the $view array and I have looped through all image instances and done as said above, I know it has worked because I have printed them out onto the page.

However it is not updating the view on the actual page, the alt tags remain the same... Please excuse my ignorance here as I am learning PHP and multidimensional keyed arrays are taking some time to sink in.

So what is the variable called for the alt tag, an object? I think that's wrong but anyway.. This variable which is ..

```
$view->result[0]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_image_front_menu['und'][0]['alt']
```

... is being changed, everything seems fine inside the function and I have tried

```
return $view
```

but to no avail.

Here is my code in entirety

```
<?php
  function image_alt_tag_alter_views_pre_render(&$view) {

    if ($view->name == "we_print_for_menu") {
    $path = arg(0) . "/" . arg(1);
    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($path);


      // loops through index in array to change each alt tag

      for ($i = 0; $i < count($view->result); ++$i) {
            $view->result[$i]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_image_front_menu['und'][0]['alt'] = $view->result[$i]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_image_front_menu['und'][0]['alt'] . $alias;
          }

      return $view;
?>
```

Comment: Is this all your code? Because it looks to me like you do not close your if or the function. also, you do not have to return anything from this function.

Comment: sorry i didnt include everything for some reason... il post below

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function image_alt_tag_alter_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  global $user;
  if ($view->name == "we_print_for_menu") {
    path = arg(0) . "/" . arg(1);
    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($path);

    dsm($view);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($view->result); ++$i) {
       $amended_alt = $view->result[$i]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_image_front_menu['und'][0]['alt'] . " " . $alias;
       $view->result[$i]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_image_front_menu['und'][0]['alt'] = $amended_alt;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Its not the proper answer. He asked about hook_views_pre_render.